# In Android, how can I display an overflow like menu when button is clicked?

Tags: android, menu, onclick, overflow

I am working on an android app and I want to make a button display a certain menu when clicked. For example, the google play music app has a overflow icon next to each icon, and when clicked, you are presented with a list of choices. How can i accomplish something liks that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ3fU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Developer Guide has a tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu

Also, given the situation, you might want this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

Comment: Thanks!! Just one last question. How can I get the list item associated with the popup menu?

Comment: This is a little more complicated. If you are trying to replicate what the google play music app is doing, you're going to have to create a custom List Adapter that extends BaseAdapter (or ArrayAdapter) and create the Popup menu in the images OnClickListener.

Comment: I realize you might have meant the position of the ListItem that was pressed (so you know which list item was pressed). To do this (if you're following the Contextual Popup guide), the `onCreateContextMenu` has a Parameter called `ContextMenuInfo` which has that info.

Comment: I set up a onclick listener on the icon within the onview created method in my custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Spinner widget. In case you are using Sherlock, you can use

Answer (score 0):

If you want it backported you can use the v7 version of popupmenu
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html